# Change Umbraco Database Connection String for Multi-Tenancy

Tags: umbraco

I'm setting up an Umbraco application with multi-tenancy where i need to change the database connection string dynamically based on the tenant selected.

i have not found any way of changing the connection string of Umbraco as it only works with the connection string named as **umbracoDbDSN** . I also have tried by downloading the source code of the Umbraco but it seems changing the ConnectionString in the Web.config file itself.

Does anyone know how can i achieve this?

Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: https://our.umbraco.com/forum/extending-umbraco-and-using-the-api/79387-one-umbraco-installation-with-muliple-databases-multi-tenant-saas

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Umbraco will work if you try and do this. When you run Umbraco as a multi-tenant install it usually uses the same DB for all the sites you run on the install.

The issue you will run into is that Umbraco will generate it's cache files etc that power the site from the DB, so every time you switch DB, those cache files will be regenerated based on the NEW database, so ALL tenets would display the content of the last database that was used.

If you need to have client specific data, you could always have a SEPARATE database for each client to store that client specific data in addition to the main core database that Umbraco uses.

Comment: Thanks Tim. If I got it correct, do I need separate database for all tenants with Umbraco?

Comment: It depends, you could store all of the tenant specific data in the same database, you'd just need a way of identifying which data belonged to each tenant.

Comment: Umbraco works well with single database. But as per my requirement, each tenant will have its own separate database. Is there any other option I can achieve this?

Comment: Not without customising the core code I don't think. You could maybe investigate Umbraco cloud, which allows you to host multiple sites that share a common "baseline" set of templates etc and see if that meets your requirements?

Comment: You cannot achieve this without running multiple sites with separate locations on disk and separate databases. Umbraco generates various temp files and indexes for caching, from which the site is run. Accessing the database constantly would be insane in regards to performance.
What you would see is likely that the indexes are being generated from the database - and if you switch out the connection string those indexes are no longer "valid". Your site may break or it may rebuild those indexes - neither of those two is a good solution for you.

Comment: @Claus, thanks for reply,  Can you help me understand and elaborate "You cannot achieve this without running multiple sites with separate locations on disk and separate databases"? What is the meaning of "multiple sites with separate locations on disk"? Also, is there any way to customize the Umbraco caching mechanism, can we achieve what we want by customization? If yes, any reference to achieve this?
Apart moving to Umbraco Cloud is there any other alternative? We have two concerns, Umbraco Cloud is costly and it doesn't allow us to choose location where to deploy.

Comment: Sure. From what it sounds like, I got the feeling you wanted to run "one application" (from one folder on your server) and dynamically switch out just the database string to achieve multi-tenancy with database isolation. As Umbraco is not really built for this, part of its caching mechanism, takes stuff out of the database and puts it on the disk for caching in indexes (inside your application folder on disk). It also isn't really built to dynamically switch out the database connection at all during runtime so actually doing this would most likely require restarting the application.

Comment: So basically if you actually did manage to do this - those generated indexes and temp files would be invalid whenever the database connection changed to a different tenant's database since they were generated from the previous tenant's database, but the site is still running within the "same location" on the disk where those are stored. Cloud will most likely not fix your problem either. You would still run multiple separate sites - the baseline feature however enables you to easier deploy changes from one central parent site to multiple child sites - they are still separate sites tho

Comment: Thanks @Claus, So what I understand is we can not achieve this even with our custom code using Umbraco. Does it mean that Umbraco Cloud architecture is specifically designed to support Same-code(One application) but multiple databases (separate for each tenant) approach?

Comment: If I understand the end goal correctly - I do not think you will be able to achieve this without modifying Core significantly by yourself (and honestly those would be major modifications you wouldn't want to do). Cloud supports that you have one primary project where you modify code (baseline). Then this can be deployed to child projects connected to it. It is however still completely separate sites running their own DB and own application. So that would be a no to your question - it is a bit different from what you are looking for I think.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Claus. In Umbraco cloud, we can deploy changes from baseline to its children, but does it also support merging changes back to master / baseline? Does it support merging changes among children internally? Also, does Umbraco cloud support DevOps concepts such as 1. Master and Dev Branch 2. Trunk based development 3. Feature Flags 4. Automated Testing and Deployment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187332/discussion-between-claus-and-developer).